# Cannot perform sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates, 13.10

I am using Ubuntu 13.10
This is what appears in the terminal when I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I was initially trying to install nodejs and I couldn't and I found an advice to run update first but this happened:

---more message above--- [cannot post 2 links]

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ph,old-releases,ubuntu,com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I saw a similar error from another forum so I tried the proposed solution but it didn't work. It says

```
"change the archive,ubuntu,com and security,ubuntu,com package repository URLs to old-releases,ubuntu,com and run update again
```

but I get the error again.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry, but Ubuntu 13.10 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 13.04 isn't an LTS version which means that it's only supported for a short period of time which was especially short for Ubuntu 13.04. The support ran out a long time ago as you can see in this graphic:
[image]

If you want to use a system that long, please use an LTS version like 14.04. You'll be provided with updates for 5 years and will be able to install new software from the repositories for at least that long.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that directly is the problem, but Ubuntu 13.10 is not supported anymore.

You should REALLY update your system(, not just some packages, that are probably not maintained anymore anyways).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help:
Open Software&Updates >>other software :uncheck all.
Also in Ubuntu software select download from "main server".
Next close>>reload..
run  **sudo apt-get update**
 then 
**sudo apt-get upgrade** (please comment your output)